# A confusion about big Oh notation

Tags: asymptotics

As far as I know, the statement $|T|\le C_M\cdot (\log N)^{-1}.|\Omega|,\ (C_M>0)$ should imply that $$|\Omega|=\mathcal{\Omega}(|T|\log N)$$ but [this seminal paper by Candes et al.](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/ExactRecovery.pdf) says in the abstract that $|\Omega|=\mathcal{O}(|T|\log N)$. I am really confused because it seems that my understanding is correct, but then how could such a seminal paper commit such a mistake, which makes me dubious about the notation used. Please help to alleviate this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in signal processing, but I don't think you're misunderstanding the notation.  The first inequality says that any $\Omega$ of size $\geq C_M^{-1} |T| \cdot \mathrm{log} N$ suffices.  The big-O notation used later is pointing out the fact that we can choose $|\Omega|$ to be approximately equal to this expression, and thus big-O of it.  It's like saying "if we choose at least 90 things, then X happens", and then celebrating the fact that fewer than 100 things suffice.

Comment: But that's not the correct use of that notation, is it?

Comment: They are being a bit imprecise when they say "almost every set of frequencies of size $O(|T| \cdot \mathrm{log} N)$"--perhaps it would be more correct to say "almost every set of frequencies of size $x$, where we can choose $x$ to be $O(|T| \cdot \mathrm{log} N)$".  In context, the other meaning is unreasonable:  for an extreme case, if $|\Omega| = 0$ (which certainly is $O(|T| \cdot \mathrm{log} N)$), then the statement couldn't possibly be correct.

Comment: Exactly @Ravi Fernando, what you said is what I was thinking (and it makes sense).